# For which numbers, every possible order can be achieved?

Tags: number-theory, cyclic-groups, carmichael-function

Let $n\ge 2$ be a natural number.

Then, every possible order of an number modulo $n$ is a divisor of $\lambda(n)$.
$\lambda(n)$ is the Carmichael-function, it is the largest possible order modulo $n$.

> Which numbers $n$ have the following property : For every $d|\lambda(n)$,
>   except $d=1$, there is a number $a$ with $1<a<n$, such that the order of $a$ modulo $n$ is $d$ ?

Additionally : If we are looking for a number a with order $2$, for which $n$ can we avoid $a=n-1$, which is trivial ?

I experimented with PARI/GP and it seems that the desired property is fulfilled, if there is a number $a$ with order $\phi(n)$ modulo $n$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29344/11619) for some stuff about finding square roots of $1$ modulo $n$. Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/345668/11619), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/25128/11619) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1449233/11619). This is one of the more frequently recurring themes.

Comment: But did I understand the main question correctly? If $a$ is of order $\lambda(n)$, and $d\mid\lambda(n)$, then $a^{\lambda(n)/d}$ is automatically of order $d$, right?

Comment: How can we be sure, that the order of $a^{\lambda(n)/d}$ is not smaller than $d$ ?

Comment: If that were the case, then the order of $a$ would also be less than $\lambda(n)$.

Comment: The general fact that holds in all groups. If $a$ is of order $m$, then $a^n$ is of order $m/\gcd(m,n)$. It suffices to prove this in a cyclic group, because everything takes place inside the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$.

Comment: Do you mean the following : We choose a number $a$ with order $\lambda(n)$ modulo $n$ and simply choose $a^{\lambda(n)/d}$ ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. Yes! The integers from 1 to n-1 that are co-prime  to n are a group  under multiplication mod n. That answers the Q :Every n .For the second part it is required that $n$ is composite and that $nx+1$ is a square for at least one $x\in \{1,...,n-1\}$. E.g. n=21 and x=3. I see you have given 2 links about this.

Comment: Seems convincing, it remains to solve the case $d=2$. When can we avoid $a=n-1$ ?

Comment: Peter, the congruence $x^2\equiv1\pmod n$ has $2^{t+e}$ pairwise incongruent solutions, where $t$ is the number of odd prime factors of $n$. The extra $e$ depends from the power of $2$ dividing $n$. If $n$ is not divisible by four, then $e=0$. If $n$ is divisible by four but not by eight, then $e=1$. If $8\mid n$, then $e=2$. That's more or less covered in the questions I linked. Chinese remainder theorem reduces the problem to the case where $n$ is a prime power, and this is what you get. You can avoid $a=n-1$, whenever $t+e>1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jyrki!

Comment: One more thing : Is there always a number $a$ with order $\lambda(n)$ modulo $n$ ?